# android project deployment and activities issue

Tags: android

i have created application in android that consist of 5 to 6 activities.
its is running successfully.i loaded the apk to my android phone where i installed and run .the question is after installing the application all the activities are shown individually in my device. why it not comprises only one files as we see about the other app that have only on file.
to many activities in device with icon separately not only confused but also make a mess.
what should i do in the eclipse project to solve it???????
thanks in advance for the replies>

Comment: Any chance you copy-pasted the activity declarations? Sounds like `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` is there with every activity, which is probably what you want to correct. Also have a read through the [`Intent` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), as that should give you all the info you may need to correct any other potential mistakes as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check android manifest file, you might have

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

in each activity tag.

Instead, you should insert this tag, only in the activity, you want on launcher menu.

Comment: you mean i only put this tag in the first activity which i want to use or display.

Comment: yes, exactly. you need to put this tag in the first activity only, which you want to use or display.

Comment: thanks , i did not tested it on device but i thinks it will work;